# Flutter bloc state value updated but navigate value empty

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc, flutter-navigation, flutter-state

I update BLOC state using this `context.read<SurveyBloc>().add(SurveyChanged(surveys: data));` in my bloc file updated value is printed but after i navigated to next page value is not updated. that also using same bloc.

bloc file snippet

```
if (event is SurveyChanged) {
      print("SurveyChanged:"+ event.surveys.survey_name);
      yield state.copyWith(surveys: event.surveys);

    }
```

this is how i update my bloc & navigate to next page

```
onTap: () {
            context.read<SurveyBloc>().add(SurveyChanged(surveys: data));
            Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                  return SurveyView();
                }));
          }
```

**surveyEvent.dart**

```
import 'package:whfms_mobile_app/models/ModelProvider.dart';

abstract class SurveyEvent {}

class SurveyHome extends SurveyEvent{

}

class SurveyResultChanged extends SurveyEvent {
  final String surveyResult;
  SurveyResultChanged({this.surveyResult});
}
class SurveyModeChanged extends SurveyEvent {
  final String mode;
  SurveyModeChanged({this.mode});
}
class SurveyChanged extends SurveyEvent {
  final Surveys surveys;
  SurveyChanged({this.surveys});
}

class SaveSurveyChanges extends SurveyEvent {}
```

**my app structer same as [this repo](https://github.com/Kilo-Loco/30DaysOfFlutter/tree/main/day24_user_profile_ui)**

Comment: can you please share your event code

Comment: Event code updated, could please check repo link, i think I need to modify app_navigator file

Comment: return a newState check the answer

Comment: @Tasnuvaoshin i replaced that in bloc file but not working

Comment: Ok check the next page . Value is null ? Then check with just string not with object . Coz if any object element is null there is a possibility of this

Answer (score 0):

```
newState = state.copyWith(surveys: event.surveys);
...
yield newState;
```